# Как получить текстовое значение имени переменной?

Tags: javascript, объекты, переменные, конструктор, properties

Например, есть конструктор:

```js
const Car = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.draw();
};
```

и я создаю новый объект:

```js
const mazda = new Car(30, 100);
```

Мне нужно в консоль получить имя переменной объекта `mazda`.
К какому свойству объекта `mazda` нужно обращаться, чтобы достучаться до названия переменной?
Или это невозможно?

Comment: Его нельзя получить, используйте объекты. (Подсказка: `Object.keys`)

Comment: нужно чтобы в консоль вывелось "mazda"? Чёт ничего не ясно

Comment: Да, нужно чтобы в консоль вывелось mazda. Короче говоря, нужно получить название переменной через свойство объекта который лежит в этой переменной.

Comment: Главный вопрос: зачем? И почему нельзя задать тип автомобилю в том же конструкторе и выводить его тип

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42791996/3129992

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const varToString = varObj => Object.keys(varObj)[0];

const Car = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

const someVar = 42;
const mazda = new Car(2, 42);

console.log(varToString({ someVar }));
console.log(varToString({ mazda }));
```

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42791996/3129992).

Докуменатация [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: Вообще конечно в данной конструкции нет никакого смысла, т.к. можно точно так же руками вывести в консоли названия. Автор хочет фигню)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский подождём и может быть автор вопроса объяснит для чего/где/зачем это используется?!